# Caching issue with Node after switching to Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, strapi

Currently in the process of migrating my Node application (built on [Strapi](https://strapi.io/)) to Docker, and running into an odd issue.

My application consists of a Strapi app serving the backend, with a static React site in the /public directory. The idea is that the root path is the React site, with the ability to access the admin panel and any other routes by hitting their respective paths.

If I access /admin or any other path directly from a fresh incognito window, I'm able to access everything per usual. However, once I visit the static React site in that session, every other path will only render the React site. Furthermore, **even when I stop the Docker container, the static site will still render for any path**.

This behavior leads me to believe there is some caching going on that I'm not accounting for, but I'm not sure where to investigate. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How come the site still works after you turn off your server (docker container)? Please include your docker settings and the code for serving the static page.

Comment: That's my primary source of confusion. The site will still load when the container is stopped, but only if it had previously been loaded in the same session. Accessing the url from an new session window will not work when the container is not running. Investigating Developer Tools shows something called service-worker.js that is loading the page when the container is stopped, but not sure entirely what role this plays.

Comment: oh, seems like your traffic is tampered by your service worker. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API